# Help with proving $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $X$ be a metric space with distance $d$ and let $p \in X$ be fixed. Define $f(x) = d(x,p)$. Prove that $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

Comment: ...please...? What's your own work and effort on this so far?

Comment: What is the definition of continuity on metric spaces ?

Comment: @Nicolas I know that the continuity on the metric space X is $\epsilon$ > 0 means that there exists $\delta$ > 0 such that d(x,p) < $delta$ d(f(p), f(x)) < $epsilon$

Comment: @ChrisMillett So write it for $f$, it should not be too difficult to see why it is continuous or not.

Comment: @Nicolas thanks! I didn't think it was that obvious sometimes

Comment: @ChrisMillett Each time you want to solve a problem in mathematics, you MUST write $1)$ your hypothesis, $2)$ what you want to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in X$ and let $N$ be a neighborhhood of $d(x,A)$ on the real line.  Choose $\epsilon>0$ small enough so that  the interval $(d(x,A)-\epsilon,d(x,A)+\epsilon)$ lies inside $N$.  Let $U$ denote the open ball centered at $x$, radius $\epsilon/2$ and choose a point $a\in A$ such that $d(x,a)<d(x,A)+\epsilon/2$.  If $z\in U$ we have 
$$d(z,A)\leq d(z,a)\leq d(z,x)+d(x,a)<d(x,A)+\epsilon$$
By reversing the roles of $x$ and $z$ we also have $d(x,A)<d(z,A)+\epsilon$.  Therefore $U$ is mapped inside $(d(x,A)-\epsilon,d(x,A)+\epsilon)$ and hence inside $N$, by our function, showing that the inverse image of $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ as required.

Answer (score 2):

Let $0 \leq a,b\in\Bbb R$, so that $I = (a,b)$ is an open interval in $\Bbb R$. Then $$f^{-1}(I) = \{x\in X : a < d(x,p) < b\} = (X\setminus \overline B(p,a))\cap B(p,b)$$
which is open in $X.$ Now note that the image of $f$ is actually $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$.$\,\blacksquare $